# To view and edit DWG files on browser

Tags: c#, dwg

I need to do the following

1. User will login to my application and upload AutoCAD file
2. User   will open the file at later date to view and edit within the browser
3. User will need the ability to Redline the document. This includes
   ability to draw lines and        basic shapes on the top of
       document.
4. User will save the revised AutoCAD file in .dwg format

I am looking for a third party development Tool Kit or API hat will allow me to
1.Display AutoCAD file within browser
2.Allow user to draw on top of it

**Note**: I cannot install anything on my client machine however browser plugin is acceptable.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `dwg` is a **proprietary** format

Comment: Is there any third party browser plugin which can help me with my requirement?